# How to undo dyntopo on a specific area?

Tags: faces, sculpting, dynamic-topology

I've been sculpting for the past couple days and realize as I move in for more detailed sculpting that I have a spot with dyntopo that I must have accidentally clicked. This was a couple days ago, so the undo button won't resolve it. I have attached a picture for a visual. Any help would be super helpful, and let me know if I need to supply anything else.

[image]

:)

EDIT: Heres an updated picture to pair with the answer that moonboots provided. It seems that changing the dyntopo to collapsed edges worked, and I just needed to play with the resolution and smooth brush to correct it out. Thanks Moon!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the *Dyntopo > Refine Method > Collapse Edges*? It will simplify your topology. Of course you need to set the good resolution, the one you'll choose will define the triangle minimum size.

Comment: I'll try that, and I'll give ya an update in a little bit!

UPDATE: So I tried that and it kinda works? It makes it more consistent with its surrounding typography, but its still sticks out like a sore thumb due to the random triangles that it creates. I'll play with the resolution and see if that can help.

Comment: once you've simplified, use a brush that will smooth the shape, like the Smooth brush

Comment: I think it worked out alright with a close enough resolution and the smooth brush. I'll post an updated pic in the question. Thanks moon :)

Answer (score 0):

Dyntopo > Refine Method > Collapse Edges > pick any Sculpt tool Strength set to 0 then apply to to your area

[image: Dyntopo > Refine Method > Collapse Edges]

[image: tool Strength set to 0]

Comment: I just uncheck this option and it works.